# Windows Mobile ArrayList

Tags: windows, mobile, arraylist

1. ArrayList / List available for windows mobile native code(c++)?
2. If available how to use it?
   I want to add items to arraylist dynamically upon runtime.

Comment: If you are talking about the .NET `ArrayList` or `List` classes, then the answer is no, because you can of course not use .NET classes in native C++.

Comment: Is there any possibility to obtain the behavior of List in native c++? because i need to add elements and after some time i need to check whether a certain element is present in the list.In my case i need a list to hold integer elements.Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/942860sh(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your useful reference.Will see if this actually helps.Is it possible for you to help me in this :                       http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/10294679/windows-mobile-backgroundworker

Comment: Thanks.i have used CLIST from your reference and it works.

Comment: I wrote this as an answer - it would be great if you could give me some credit for providing a solution :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make this an answer you can give me credit for:

Please see the reference for the Microsoft Foundation Classes. There are collection classes you can use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/942860sh(v=vs.80).aspx