# Windows Mobile BackgroundWorker

Tags: windows, windows-mobile

How to use background worker in windows mobile native code(c++) for async tasks.

Comment: Can you clarify your question. Is it Windows or Android? C++ or C#? I am confused...

Comment: sorry.I have removed that android tag.Actually i need the behavior of Android's asynctask in windows mobile's native c++. I found that in c# , backgroundworker class helps but i need the functionality in native c++. Can you help me?

Comment: If you want parallel processing (using C++) the best thing you can do is to look at the [Boost Library (MPI)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/mpi.html), but this is parallel processing in the truest sense (not really 'threading') - for threading you want the [Boost Thread library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread.html). I hope this helps.

Comment: Third party library?. Can you help me with any msdn kind of direct reference?Thanks

Comment: There's not `BackgroundWorker` in the native API. `BackgroundWorker` is .NET specific.

Comment: I need similar functionality in native c++. Is it possible?

Comment: As far as I am aware, there is no native library that deals with threading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is really vague but, generally speaking, background tasks are done with threads.  Those are created in C by calling [the CreateThread API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202727.aspx).  Examples for usage abound on the web.  [Here's one](http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/CandCPP/270487/270487/createthread-windows-threading/) that just happened to be at the top of the search engine results for me today.